# jquery send object inside object to controller

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, controller

I am having java object as object A contains object B and Object B contains object C, Here is my oject as follows

```
public class objectA{
 private String name;
 private String college;
 private objectB obj; 
 }
 public class objectB{
 private String address;
 private String dept;
 private objectC obj; 
 }
 public class objectC{
 private String bus;
 private String bike;

 }
```

I have to send objectA from **jsp** to **controller** how to make object objectA in jquery and here is my ajax code

```
$("#SaveBtnId").click(function() {

        **HOW TO MAKE OBJECT A**

        $.ajax({
            url : "../seller/addSeller",
            type : "post",
            data : objectA,
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("Saved Successfully");
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert(error);
                alert("Details failed to save");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: http is a text based protocol

Comment: yes, I am passing as JSON object from jsp to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code creates a model for you which you can pass to your controller.
Try and let me know if you face any issue.

```
$("#SaveBtnId").click(function() {

ObjectC:{
bus:$('#txtBus').val(), //Considering as getting from textBox
dept:$('#txtBike').val(),
};

ObjectB:{
address:$('#txtAdd').val(), //Considering as getting from textBox
dept:$('#dept').val(),
obj:ObjectC
};

ObjectA:{
name: $('#txtName').val(),
college: $('#txtCollege').val(),
obj:ObjectB
};
        $.ajax({
            url : "../seller/addSeller",
            type : "post",
            data : JSON.stringify(objectA),
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {
                alert("Saved Successfully");
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert(error);
                alert("Details failed to save");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: its working fine thanks for suggesting the above answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#SaveBtnId").click(function() {

   var a = {};
   var b = {};
   var c = {};
   c['bus'] = 'bus';
   c['bike'] = 'bike';

   b['address'] = 'address';
   b['dept'] = 'dept'
   b['objectC'] = c;

   a['name'] = 'name';
   a['college'] = 'college';
   a['objectB'] = b;



    $.ajax({
        url : "../seller/addSeller",
        type : "post",
        data : JSON.strigify(a),
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert("Saved Successfully");
        },
        error : function(error) {
            alert(error);
            alert("Details failed to save");
        }
    });
});
```

This could be helpful. 
Note that all three class must have setters and getters.